# EC2 instance settings user data option not present

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t2.small AWS EC2 instance and I want to edit the user data to add a cloud-init script.

I took down the instance as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), but I run into a problem:

there is no `Edit user data` option in `Actions > instance settings`

[image: screenshot showing that the option is not there]

I looked all over google but cannot find anything on this, does anyone know what's up?

Comment: I just started and stopped an EC2 instance and can edit the instance metadata. If no-one else can work it out ask AWS support, costs $50 a month for developer level support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the old console did the trick, there were far more options there. Apparently they haven't implemented everything yet in their new console.

Answer (score 0):

The action is available but requires scrolling in the menu to see it if the table height is small. So just scroll down in the menu to see the action.